# What happens when the Nazgul breaks the stick of Gandalf?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

During the Rohan war in *The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King*, there is an encounter between Gandalf and a Nazgul. As far as I remember the Nazgul breaks the stick of Gandalf. I need to know the details of that scene as the scene is clipped in most of the versions of the movie.

Comment: Ahem, it's a wizard, staff, not a stick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen the extended version of the movie, and nothing else really happens.
The Witch King of Angmar hears the Rohan army arriving, and goes to deal with them.  Also notice that the scene in the books is actually different, he never "overpowers" Gandalf.

Answer (score 0):

So I re watched the scene and now I understand what it means. Remember when we first see the Balrog it was wielding a fire sword? It tried to strike Gandalf down but Gandalf's staff meets the sword and the sword shatters, this is because both object and magic at their core and Gandalf's Magic was stronger than the Balrog's.

When Gandalf confronts the Witch King, the Witch King says. "Do you not know death when you see it? It is my force." So what I got out of that was that, because their was a battle going on, he was getting stronger and was at that time, able to beat Gandalf. So when the Witch King draws his sword that is like his weapon, opposing Gandalf's and, because the Witch King was stronger in his magic, Gandalf's staff shatters just like the Balrog's sword.